# Как отправить json на сервер python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

Задача, отправить json на сервер.

```
import requests as req
json_tmp = Тут json
req.post(f"https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0/orders/add?access_token={Iico.getToken()}&request_timeout=1000", ?)
```

Проблема - не понимаю, как прикрепить json к пост запросу. По документации юзал так:

```
req.post(f"https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0/orders/add?access_token={Iico.getToken()}&request_timeout=1000", data=json_tmp)
```

Но получал 400/415. Явно, что-то не то пуляет на сервак.
В postman тестил запрос с json, все было четко.

Comment: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: Я же написал, что data так не работает. Как я понял, оно добавляет еще какой-то form: { 
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

r = requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post", json={"foo": "bar"})
```

Ещё так json можно отправить:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post", data=json.dumps({"foo": "bar"}))
```

Comment: А как именно переменную передавать ? У меня очень большой json

Comment: Через именованный аргумент json, второй вариант для старых версий requests